# HTTP get with query parameters and storing xml response on disc java

Tags: java, xml, http

I have a http end point which serves xml responses to my queries. I tried to fire the http requests like this -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class c {

   public String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
      URL url;
      HttpURLConnection conn;
      BufferedReader rd;
      String line;
      String result = "";
      try {
         url = new URL(urlToRead);
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
         rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         // how to store the response as an xml file on disc
         rd.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return result;
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     c c = new c();
     System.out.println(c.getHTML(args[0]));
   }
}
```

Now, the endpoint sends xml response which i want to store as a xml file on disc. how can i do that. can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but maybe you could start from something like this:

```
String dest = "c:\\filename.xml";
// this line substitutes your rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
// these others goes in your "how to store..." comment
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```